# Jetty: HTTP ERROR: 503/ Service Unavailable

Tags: java, xml, jetty

I'm new to Jetty, I tried to run the sample program here "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128145/Run-Jetty-Web-Server-Within-Your-Application" 
but I got error message on my page "http://localhost:8585/runJetty/"

```
"HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /runJetty/. Reason: 
    Service Unavailable
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty:// "
```

Error log I get from eclipse:

```
2012-04-20 11:14:32.522:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.3.v20120416
2012-04-20 11:14:32.617:WARN:oejx.XmlParser:FATAL@file:/C:/Users/***/workspace/Test/WEB-INF/web.xml line:1 col:7 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
2012-04-20 11:14:32.617:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/runJetty,file:/C:/Users/***/workspace/Test/}
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setWebXml(MetaData.java:165)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at blog.runjetty.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:22)
at blog.runjetty.ui.listener.ServerStartStopActionListner.actionPerformed(ServerStartStopActionListner.java:38)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2012-04-20 11:14:32.648:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8585
```

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
version="2.4">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My JSP file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Embedding Jetty</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Running Jetty web server from our application!!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rolled back to the original question. If you have another question, please *do not* replace this one with it. Just ask a new question. Also, if the answer helped you solve the problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I solved the problem. I run it by eclipse jetty plugin.

1. I didn't have the JDK lib in my eclipse, that's why the message keep showing that I need the full JDK installed, that's the main reason.
2. I installed two versions of jetty plugin, wich is jetty7 and jetty8. I think they conflict with each other or something, so I removed the jetty7, and it works!

Comment: I had a bit similar issue, for some (now unknown) reason I had added tomcat jasper-compiler into my pom for a test setup and was wondering why it did not start with the same setup as normally. Took that out and worked like a charm afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

> 2012-04-20 11:14:32.617:WARN:oejx.XmlParser:FATAL@file:/C:/Users/***/workspace/Test/WEB-INF/web.xml line:1 col:7 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

You Log says, that you web.xml is malformed. Line 1, colum 7. It may be a UTF-8 [Byte-Order-Marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Try to verify, that your xml is wellformed and does not have a BOM. Java doesn't use BOMs.

Comment: Without the web.xml no one can help.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me.

I had to remove all deployed java web app:

- Windows/Show View/Other...
- Go the the Server folder and select "Servers"
- Right-click on the J2EE Preview at localhost
- Click to Add and Remove... Click Remove all

Then run the project on the server

The Error is gone!

You will have to stop the server before deploying another project because it will not be found by the server. Otherwise you will get a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by removing the line break from the xml file. I did

```
<operationBindings>
    <OperationBinding>
        <operationType>update</operationType>
        <operationId>makePdf</operationId>
        <serverObject>
            <className>com.myclass</className>
            <lookupStyle>new</lookupStyle>
        </serverObject>
        <serverMethod>makePdf</serverMethod>
    </OperationBinding>
</operationBindings>
```

instead of ...

```
<serverObject>
            <className>com.myclass
</className>
            <lookupStyle>new</lookupStyle>
</serverObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Delete the project from workspace. and Reimport the project to the workspace.
This method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"Project... Clean" in Eclipse solved this for me.

Earlier, I had to configure the web.xml correctly.